# Blazor isn't creating new namespace for new path in root

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I created two folders called Authentication and WebComponents and Blazor created namespaces for them no problem. But today I tried to create another called MemberComponents and it won't create a namespace for it.

Is there a workaround for this? I've tried restarting VS2019 and adding razor components in the MemberComponents with no success. [image: r]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add a class file inside the folder `MemberComponents` for Visual Studio to add namespace in intellisense. Folders don't create namespaces, class files in the folders create namespaces if they exist.

```
namespace AppTemplate.Client.Shared.MemberComponents
{

}
```

Comment: wow it worked, thank you! I never added a class file to the Authentication and WebComponents yet it created namespaces for it so adding a class totally went over my head.